Do statistical properties of particles violate conservation of energy?
Electrons can "tunnel" through an energy barrier to appear on the other side. This is because the probability that a particle appears somewhere is never zero, even if very small.
However, taking this to its logical conclusion, the probability that a particle appears away from a gravitational body is also non-zero, ie the probability that a particle gains potential energy is non-zero. This would appear to violate conservation of energy at least locally. What gives?
Is quantum tunneling only possible when the effect would not increase the potential energy of the particle, ie, can particles gain potential energy from quantum tunneling? Where does this energy come from?

Quantum tunneling in particular usually regards jumping across potential barriers, not onto them.

So the probability of jumping onto a potential barrier is zero?

Not necessarily - what I mean is that you should be clear what you mean by quantum tunneling. Of course I could observe a particle and see that it did just move slightly farther away from the Earth and gain GPE as it's height increased slightly, but over a large number of observations I'd see an equal number of particles move closer to the Earth and the total energy change would be zero, I imagine.

So the energy always comes from somewhere, or gets canceled out by the system?

Sort of. See Connor’s answer - essentially, yes, particles can spontaneously gain energy, but over time, the spontaneous gains/losses/no-ops cancel out so that the expectation value of energy is conserved.

That's actually pretty amazing.

An s-wave function decays exponentially in a 1/r potential, so the probability that one would find a quantum far away from the center is vanishing very quickly. The problem with "energy extraction" from such a scheme is that the system with an actual quantum detector at a finite distance does not behave like the free system. That is rarely mentioned in textbooks as far as I know. Same for a "particle that jumps across a potential barrier". The plane waves at infinity, however, reflect the classically expected energy values.

Energy is an operator whose expectation value is conserved as a result of Ehrenfest's theorem. For some operator $\hat{O}$, unitary evolution gives
\begin{align}
\langle \psi | \hat{O} | \psi \rangle \mapsto \langle \psi | e^{iHt / \hbar} \hat{O} e^{-iHt / \hbar} | \psi \rangle.
\end{align}
This implies
\begin{align}
\frac{d\hat{O}}{dt} = \frac{i}{\hbar}[H, \hat{O}]
\end{align}
which is the Heisenberg equation of motion. The Hamiltonian obviously commute with itself so this derivative is zero for $\hat{O} = H$.
Regarding your example, quantum mechanics doesn't just predict that tunneling can happen. It also forces you to dispense with the notion that particles at position $x$ necessarily have energies $E \geq V(x)$. The first demonstration of tunneling that we see comes from finding a stationary solution of the Schroedinger equation. I.e. an energy eigenstate. For a given $E$, these eigenstates generically have support on positions $x$ such that $E \leq V(x)$.
So if you see particle A close to a planet and particle B far away, you can't say particle B has more potential energy. Maybe they are both in energy eigenstates and $E_A > V(x_A)$ but $E_B < V(x_B)$. This would be an example of particle B exhibiting classically forbidden behaviour explaining how it can have less energy than A. If you want to say that particle B, since it's observed to be far away "collapses" into the $x_B$ position eigenstate then that's fine. The energy $E_B$ is then governed by a probability distribution which peaks at a value above $E_A$ like we classically expect. So in that sense you can say that energy is not conserved. But this is of course because collapse is not unitary and violates the assumptions that go into Ehrenfest's theorem.

I did some more thinking and came to the conclusion that the energy must come from somewhere and if I had perfect knowledge of a particle's state then a change in potential energy would mean a change in some other energy, whether kinetic, thermal, or otherwise (from another particle), so the total energy is conserved. Is that essentially what your answer says?

Sort of. If a particle has definite energy at all then this energy cannot change. You will be able to observe it near Mercury at one moment and near Pluto at the next. And the state that allows both of those possibilities will have only one energy for all time. The closest thing to "changes in energy" that make sense are changes in particular samplings of the random variable for energy. And then you can say that a gain in one observation is "borrowed" by a loss from another observation.

So what's the catch here? Is it just that we can't determine which gains and losses correlate?

There shouldn't be any correlation like that because they just have to cancel on average. This means that if you prepare identical copies of a system, the energies you measure at time $t_1$ will have an average which is the same as that of the energies you measure at time $t_2$. As the number of measurements $N \to \infty$ of course.

I see. So a way to test this is to apply random energy redistributions to a group of particles, and this will always result in a state that has the same total energy as at the start?

The way to test this is to have 200 copies of the same system. For the first 100, measure energy after a second and average. For the second 100, measure energy after two seconds and average.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
